# background-image: url() not working & image not showing up too

Tags: html, css

My Background image is not showing up on the site. I am using HTML5 with CSS. Here is the corresponding code.

```
 body {
        width: 1000px;
        background-image: url(background.jpg);
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        background-color:#D1E1E1;
        }
```

Secondly, when i try to view the image by accessing the URL, for e.g. myurl[dot]com/background.jpg

But, the Image is present on my server. When, i go to my FileManager, and click on view the image, it correctly shows up.

My whole site loads up, instead of the image. This is very strange behaviour and i am not aware of it. I looked up the net and could not find any solution.

**EDIT:** When, i run this code on my own computer(localhost), the site works correctly.

Comment: Do you have a link we can look at? perhaps see the entire site working, not just look at this bit of code? The style definition looks okay to me - the syntax is okay.

Comment: @Leigh I have Added the Link.

Comment: @Ernesto I have tried that already. Did not help.

Comment: Try to view your page in Chrome and open the Web Developer Tools. Go there to the Network tab and you'll see what's wrong with your request. I'm 99% sure the path to the image is wrong.

Comment: If I go to "http://random.uiet.org/background.jpg" in my browser it takes me back to the index. I think you have something wrong in your server settings or permissions.

Comment: @Poru Thanks a Lot. You Were almost right. The File permissions were set incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Check file permissions, it should be at least 644, but just make it 777

If this doesn't help, have you ever played with your .htaccess file?

Comment: Well, I just did that. And it fixed the Problem.

**Why this error Occured**

Whenever, a new image is uploaded to the server, its permissions are set to 600 by deafult.

Comment: Server might be configured by default to set those rights. You could try to make a folder, set correct rights to it and upload files into it. See if rights of those uploaded files are still same as default ones

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some kind of rewrite rule applied on the server. it always returns your home page, no matter what you type in the address line.

Btw, dont know how to respond just as comment and not post as answer..sorry

Comment: You have to have a minimum of 50 reputation to post new comments. Once your reputation goes above 50, you'll see the "add comment" links.

Answer (score 0):

Your image paths aren't right, for what's on your server.

When I go to the site, and type in http://random.uiet.org/style.css I see your stylesheet. By your styledef, I should also be able to view your background image. But when I go to http://random.uiet.org/background.jpg I just see the whole site - not any image at all. So it's possible that the server is set up to generate no 404 error pages.

Where, on the server, is your background.jpg file? What's its full path?